# xbee arduino communication programming

Tags: c++, arduino, xbee

I tried testing the system and I’m not sure if the problem is with the xbee’s, the transmitting code, or the recieveing code.  Before I post my code I will explain what we are doing with the signals.  We have three analog signals that will be sent serially through one xbee using an arduino and xbee shield.  We want to send these signals to the receiving xbee where the arduino will output these signals to be connected to a third arduino through wires to be used in a Simulink program.  We are using an arduino mega for the transmitting side and an arduino uno for the receiving side. I was told I need to do serial streaming but I’m not sure how that’s done.  I understand the xbee and arduinos both digitize signals but we are hoping to get a signal very similar to the analog signals we are transmitting.  Any amount of help is greatly appreciated!!
This is how I have my xbees configured (series 1) both in AT mode:

> **Transmitting Xbee:**
>   Channel:10
>   Pan id: 1234
>   MY: 10
>   DL: 11
>   **Receiving  Xbee:**
>   Channel:10
>   Pan ID: 1234
>   MY: 11
>   DL: 10

transmitting Arduino code:

```
void setup() {  
    Serial.begin(9600);  
}  
void loop() {  
// read the input on analog pins  
int sensorValue1 = analogRead(A0);  
int sensorValue2 = analogRead(A1);  
int sensorValue3 = analogRead(A2);  
// print out the value you read:  
Serial.println(sensorValue1);  
Serial.println(sensorValue2);  
Serial.println(sensorValue3);  
delay(1);          
}
```

**Receiving Arduino code:**

```
int received1=8;  
int received2=9;  
int received3=10;  
void setup(){  
    pinMode(received1, OUTPUT);  
    pinMode(received2, OUTPUT);  
    pinMode(received3, OUTPUT);  
    Serial.begin(9600);  
}  
void loop(){  
    if(Serial.available() )  
    {  
        byte output1 = Serial.read();  
        byte output2 = Serial.read();  
        byte output3 = Serial.read();  
        digitalWrite(received1, HIGH);  
        digitalWrite(received2, HIGH);  
        digitalWrite(received3, HIGH);  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're using the XBee modules in "AT mode" or "transparent serial" mode where anything received on the serial port of module A is sent out of the serial port of module B, and vice versa.

If that's the case, it may help to do your initial development with the serial ports of your two devices connected directly to each other.  Work out your serial protocol there, and then try to run it with the XBee modules in place as a serial cable replacement.

Consider the format of the data that you're sending, and how you will process it on the other end.  How will you separate the readings and identify which analog input they belong to?  With your current code, you print the readings on separate lines, but it won't be clear which is `A0`.  Maybe you want to send them on a single line with a comma in between each reading?

On the receiving end, you need to convert the text back to an integer using a C function like `atoi()` or `strtoul()`.

If you're trying to create an analog output on the Arduino, it might be possible with a digital output that's using PWM (pulse width modulation). This [Instructable](http://www.instructables.com/id/Analog-Output-Convert-PWM-to-Voltage/) does a decent job of describing that concept.